# curve plot and histogram on the same frame with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I want a curve and an histogram to coexist on the same plot with matplotlib. The curve is a normal curve and the histogram is made out of a dataset. I want to compare the histogram (real repartition of my sample) to the curve (what my sample's repartition should be if I had a ton of data). The goal is to check if there is an other factor than hazard.

Here's the code :

```
def testHistogram(arr, mean, variance):
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.stats as stats
    import math

    # histogram
    num_bins = 100
    plt.hist(arr, num_bins, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)

    # plot
    mu = mean
    sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
    x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 100)
    plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma))

    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

My problem is, the curve does not appear. (The histogram seems to work fine).

parameters :

- `arr` : a list of values (the sample I want to compare to the curve)
- `mean` : the mean of the sample, in order to build the corresponding curve
- `variance` : the variance of the sample, in order to build the corresponding curve

EDIT : As asked in a comment, here's how to create the parameters :

```
#create a dataset for testing - i am getting it from a database 
import random
myList = []
while (i<100):
    randomnumber = random.randint(1,100)
    myList.append(randomnumber)
    i = i+1
#get the mean and variance of the dataset
count = 0
sum = 0
squaresSum = 0
theMean = 0
for onedata in dataset:
    count = count+1
    sum = sum + onedata
    squaressum = squaresSum + onedata*onedata
theMean = sum/count
theVariance = squaresSum/count - theMean*theMean

# launch the function
testHistogram(myList, theMean, theVariance)
```

Comment: Your code does not work. Can you provide a code which work? which we can simply copy to reproduce your figure? Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your code almost works, you just need to normalize the histogram. [scipy.stats.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) returns a normalized curve, that is, the integral of the curve is 1.
In your case, you probably have a very low curve almost flattened on the x axis which you cannot see.

To normalize the histogram, simply pass the parameter `density = True` to the `hist` function:

```
plt.hist(arr, num_bins, density=True, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)
```

For example, the following code (a small reworking of yours):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math

def testHistogram(arr, mean, variance):
    # histogram
    num_bins = 100
    plt.hist(arr, num_bins, density=True, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)

    # plot
    mu = mean
    sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
    x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 100)
    plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma))

    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()


mm = 100  #norm mean valu
vv = 40   #norm variance
#x is an array of 100 random numbers from the normal distribution
x = np.random.normal(mm, math.sqrt(vv), 100)
testHistogram(x, mm, vv)
```

draws the following figure:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was doing wrong and your correction is what I needed.